# R - textcat not executing because of supposed invalid UTF-8 strings

Tags: r, utf-8

I'm trying to run a seemingly simple task, trying to identify the languages of a vector of text using the 'textcat' package. I've cleaned the text data (a sample of tweets) so as to only be left with standard characters, however, when I try to execute the textcat command as follows

```
text.df$language <- textcat(text.df$text)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in textcnt(x, n = max(n), split = split, tolower = tolower, marker = marker,  : 
  not a valid UTF-8 string
```

Despite the fact that the following test

```
nchar(text.df$text, "c", allowNA=TRUE)
```

suggested that there are no non-utf8 characters in the data.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `iconv` on your input text...

```
text <- "iðŸ’™you"
> iconv(text, "UTF8", "ASCII", sub="")
[1] "iyou"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm afraid I still get the same error message when I run textcat...

Comment: You will probably need to provide a reproducible example for this problem to be solved here.